# Does object destructuring while require cause memory leak in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, memory-management, memory-leaks, node-modules

I am building an application where memory is very costly. I have imported modules and constants as shown below in multiple files. Does it cause memory leak?. My understanding is that `require('module_name')` is singleton but if we use it along with object destructuring then new variables are created for each require. Now if below style is used throughout the project then its too much variable declaration right?

user_controller.js

```js
const { createUser, updateUser } = require('user_manager'); // importing functions from user module
const { APPLICATION: USER_LIMIT } = require('config'); // importing constants from config file
```

user_manager.js

```js
const createUser = () {
  // Some code here
}

const updateUser = () {
  // Some code here
}

module.exports = {
  createUser,
  updateUser
}
```

config.js

```
module.exports = {
  APPLICATION: {
    USER_LIMIT: 10,
    // Many such constants.
  }
}
```

Small experiment on object destructuing:

index.js

```js
var { name, getName } = require('./module1')
var module1 = require('./module1')
var module2 = require('./module2');

console.log(`local name Before: ${name}`);
console.log(`local name Before: ${getName()}`);
name = "Alex";
console.log(`local name After: ${name}`);
console.log(`local name After: ${getName()}`);
console.log(`Module1 name After: ${module1.name}`);
console.log(`Module1 name After: ${module1.getName()}`);

console.log(`Module2 name Before: ${module2.name}`);
console.log(`Module2 name Before: ${module2.getName()}`);
module2.name = "Ajax";
console.log(`Module2 name After: ${module2.name}`);
console.log(`Module2 name After: ${module2.getName()}`);
```

module1.js

```js
const Module1 = require("../require_vs_new/Module1");

module.exports = {
  name: "Dheemanth",
  getName: function () {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

module2.js

```js
module.exports = {
  name: "Dheemanth",
  getName: function () {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, it's behaving normally:
The destructured "name" variable has "Dheemanth" value until you override it with "Alex".
The destructured "getName" variable is a function where "this" refers to nothing so the returned value is undefined.
Your module1 tests behaves normally, "getName"  is attached to it so "this" is defined.
Your module2 tests also behaves normally and you are able to change the returned value by overwriting "module.name".
You may want to read about the [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) keyword that it a bit special in javascript.

Comment: Hey ya its behaving as expected. I am concerned about memory leak. if u observe `module1` did not change its `name` property but `module2` name property got changed. That is what i wanted to show.